# PHP - How to get tokens?

Tags: php, validation, token

I was told I needed to validate the tokens below but I'm not sure where to start. I only have public access to the website I'm pulling the data from. Someone explain to me tokens or give an example to get me moving?

Do I need access to the other server?

```
function send_CAD($number, $street, $website, $f_opts = true){         
    $year   = date('Y', time());    
    $number = trim($number);
    $street = urlencode(trim($street));
    $post_data = "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&".
                 "__VIEWSTATE=/wEPD...&" .
                 "__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWNw...&".
                 "txtAddrNum=$number&listStDir=&";
...
```

Comment: Does "tokens" refer to what's in `$post_data`?

Comment: Yea, __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATE are tokens.

Comment: One would expect that the site you're working with has some kind of API documentation available.

Comment: I thought so too but this is a government site =\

Comment: I find that statement really funny. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will get you started in the right direction... http://www.devcomments.com/Need-help-with-cURL-and-https-Post-to-ASP-Net-site-to221695.htm

Comment: Actuall i was the one who left the comment on his other question which probably led him to post this one. It seemed to me that `__EVENTVALIDATION` seemed like it was some kind of token to validate the request. So I asked him if he had actually made a request prior to the one for his search to et a valid token for `_EVENTVALIDATION`. Essentially I was trying to confirm he had tried what is outlined in that devcomments link sberry posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking so here's the answer in both directions:

If you have a full url that you're trying to parse, use `parse_url`:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

If you have only the query part of the url you can use `parse_str`:

```
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

If you have a url that you're trying to construct use `http_build_query`:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data); // foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

If you need to do validation on the data, once you've gotten it, you can use the built in `filter_input` functions with validation/sanitizing options in PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Example from `filter_validate_array` page:

```
/* data actually came from POST
$_POST = array(
    'product_id'    => 'libgd<script>',
    'component'     => '10',
    'versions'      => '2.0.33',
    'testscalar'    => array('2', '23', '10', '12'),
    'testarray'     => '2',
);
*/

$args = array(
    'product_id'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'component'    => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'     => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY, 
                            'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 10)
                           ),
    'versions'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'doesnotexist' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'testscalar'   => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                           ),
    'testarray'    => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
                           )

);

$myinputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

var_dump($myinputs);
echo "\n";
```

The above example will output:

```
array(6) {
  ["product_id"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0] => string(17) "libgd%3Cscript%3E"
      }
  ["component"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0] => int(10)
      }
  ["versions"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0] => string(6) "2.0.33"
      }
  ["doesnotexist"]=>
      NULL
  ["testscalar"]=>
      bool(false)
  ["testarray"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0] => int(2)
      }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved my issues completely.

Answer (score 0):

VIEWSTATE etc are used in ASP.NET.  There is nothing you need to do with them when processing them in PHP.  If the ASP.NET is posting a form to your php page, you can do some quick analysis by doing:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE)."</pre>";
```

and try to figure out which of the items you should be interested in.  Then you can simply get those items by doing, for e.g.:

```
$itemid = $_REQUEST['itemid'];
```

You can ignore the 'tokens' that you dont need to process.

You should try and replace $_REQUEST with either $_GET or $_POST based on how your php page is being called.